# I'm creating a poker client, how can I make the exception handling more clean?

Tags: java, exception, coding-style

I'm checking if the values are valid. The `if parts` looks still messy for me, checking a lot of `||` operator, and there is multiple `InvalidArgumentException`, but I always check for that.

How can this be more clean ?

This is part of my script :

```
public Card(String cardCode) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    this.cardCode = cardCode;

    String cardColor = this.cardCode.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    String cardValue = cardCode.substring(1).toUpperCase();
    Integer intCardValue = Integer.parseInt(cardValue);

    if (!colors.contains(cardColor))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("card color isn't valid: " + cardColor);
    }

    if (alphabeticCardValue.get(cardValue) == null || intCardValue > 10 || intCardValue < 2 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("card number isn't valid: " + intCardValue);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually trying to do is validating the input. Using `IllegalArgumentException` is not appropriate, imo, because the purpose is of this exception is defined in JavaDoc as follows:

> - Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or 
>     inappropriate argument.

What I would do is as follows:

1. Define an enum for possible colors:

   ```
   public enum Color { BLACK, RED, ... }
   ```
2. Define an enum for possible card values:

   ```
   public enum CardValues {
       TWO(2),
       THREE(3); // ...

       private int value;

       private CardValues(final int v) {
           value = v;
       }

       public getValue() { return value;}
   }
   ```
3. Change the constructor as follows:

   ```
   public Card(Color color, CardValues cardValues) {
       if (color == null || cardValues == null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("....");
       }
       // doSomething else
   }
   ```

   Note: `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception. So you don't need to specify it in the `throws` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by putting the check into a separate method?
Something like `isValidCard()` and `isValidColor()`, so you can create a method `isValidCard()` using those methods.

Edit: Just go with ujulu's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you check the values in the constructor you can make sure all the cards will be  valid. There's a downside - you'll have to decide which (valid) card will be created when the constructor is called with invalid parameters.